# Cannot start settings from action bar

Tags: java, android

Starting to learn about creating the settings page, but my app crashes when I select 'settings' from the action bar, and I get this error in logcat:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myexamlpe.thing.Preference cannot be cast to android.app.Activity`

Here's how I call it from my main class:

```
public class RCs extends FragmentActivity implements
    rcfrequency.ToolbarListener, RCButtons.ToolbarListener {
.
.
.

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Preference.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Here's my Preference class:

```
public class Preference extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener  {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens because you are trying to open a `PreferenceFragment` as a `PreferenceActivity`

```
public class Preference extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener  {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

The error is cast, because its Preference class inherits from PreferenceFragment soon there may not be opened as an Activity

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myexamlpe.thing.Preference cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

change to :

```
public class Preference extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener  {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

See a example here, how to use `PreferenceFragment`:

http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture12/lecture12.html

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. The tutorial I was using said to use PreferenceFragment over PreferenceActivity because it is no longer used above API 11.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you declare `class Preference extends PreferenceFragment` but try to start it with an `Intent`. As Andre stated, you can fix this by extending `PreferenceActivity`. Alternatively, you can use a the `FragmentManager` to display your `Preference`. This requires learning a little about fragments and how they interact with activities. This is what was meant by the suggestion that you should use `PreferenceFragment` over `PreferenceActivity`.

Comment: Yeah I suppose I've been putting off learning about `FragmentManager` for too long now. Guess I'll start on that next. Thanks